# For loop over a group_by when passing in a variable name

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply

I'm trying to program an R function that will extract the proportion of positives in a community based on column value.  More concretely, I have a dataset where each row is an individual.  To simplify, column 1-5 has information about their individual characteristics, while column 6 has zip code, column 7 has the phone number they called to report a positive, column 8 has the day of the week, and column 9 has state.  The goal is to calculate the proportion and number of positives at the aggregate level for zip code, phone number, day of the week, and state.  For any one category, I successfully used code from https://edwinth.github.io/blog/dplyr-recipes/ to build a group and summarize function (below).  Feed in a dataframe and column name and it will group by the distinct values on that column and summarize the count and proportion of positives.

```
group_and_summarize <- function(x, ...) {
  grouping = rlang::quos(...)
  temp = x %>% group_by(!!!grouping) %>% summarise(proportion = mean(positive, na.rm = TRUE), number = n()) 
  temp = temp %>% filter(!is.na(!!!grouping))
  colnames(temp)[2] = paste0(colnames(temp)[1], "_proportion")
  colnames(temp)[3] = paste0(colnames(temp)[1], "_count")
  return(temp)
}
```

Problem is, that code fails entirely when I try to aggregate across multiple columns.  I currently have four fields to group over, but once the data are fully gathered, I expect to have ~15 columns.  My strategy here is to store each of those as a separate element of a list for later use.  I tried to use

```
output = vector(mode = "list", length = length(aggregate_cols)) #aggregate_cols lists columns needing count and proportion.
    #aggregate_cols = c("ZIP_CODE", "PHONE_NUMBER", "DAY", "STATE")
for(i in 1:length(aggregate_cols)){
output[i] = group_and_summarize(df,aggregate_cols[i])
          }
```

but got the following error message

```
Warning messages:
1: In output[i] <- group_and_summarize(df, aggregate_cols[i]) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In output[i] <- group_and_summarize(df, aggregate_cols[i]) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
3: In output[i] <- group_and_summarize(df, aggregate_cols[i]) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
4: In output[i] <- group_and_summarize(df, aggregate_cols[i]) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Testing for the first value

```
> i=1
> group_and_summarize(df,aggregate_cols[i])
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  `aggregate_cols[i]`  proportion number
  <chr>                 <dbl>  <int>
1 ZIP_CODE              0.168   5600
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?  I can't think of a good way involving map or the apply family of functions, although I'd be open to those.

EDIT:

Reproducible code is below.

```
group_and_summarize_demo <- function(x, ...) {
  grouping = quos(...)
  temp = x %>% group_by(!!!grouping) %>% summarise(proportion = mean(am, na.rm = TRUE), number = n()) 
  temp = temp %>% filter(!is.na(!!!grouping))
  colnames(temp)[2] = paste0(colnames(temp)[1], "_proportion")
  colnames(temp)[3] = paste0(colnames(temp)[1], "_count")
  return(temp)
}

cars_cols = c("gear", "cyl")
output = vector(mode = "list", length = length(cars_cols))
for(i in 1:length(cars_cols)){
  output[i] = group_and_summarize_demo(df,cars_cols[i]) #group_and_summarize gets count and proportion
}


> group_and_summarize_demo(mtcars, cyl)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
    cyl cyl_proportion cyl_count
  <dbl>          <dbl>     <int>
1     4          0.727        11
2     6          0.429         7
3     8          0.143        14
> cars_cols = c("gear", "cyl")
> output = vector(mode = "list", length = length(cars_cols))
> for(i in 1:length(cars_cols)){
+   output[i] = group_and_summarize_demo(df,cars_cols[i]) #group_and_summarize gets count and proportion
+ }
 Show Traceback
 
 Rerun with Debug
 Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "function" 
> cars_cols[1]
[1] "gear"
> group_and_summarize_demo(mtcars, cars_cols[1])
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  `cars_cols[1]` `cars_cols[1]_proportion` `cars_cols[1]_count`
  <chr>                              <dbl>                <int>
1 gear                               0.406                   32
```

I don't understand why this is different from running group_and_summarize_demo(mtcars,cyl); I suspect understanding that will address this bug.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside your loop, you are passing the name directly to the function:

```
group_and_summarize_demo(mtcars, cyl)
```

However, inside your loop, you are passing the name as a string:

```
group_and_summarize_demo(mtcars, "cyl") #error
```

Indeed, using a string is easier in this setting. In order for this to work, you should not use `quos()` but `syms()`:

```
group_and_summarize_demo <- function(x, ..., quosure=TRUE) {
  if(quosure)
    grouping = quos(...)
  else
    grouping = syms(...)
  temp = x %>% 
    group_by(!!!grouping) %>% 
    summarise(proportion = mean(am, na.rm = TRUE), number = n()) 
  temp = temp %>% filter(!is.na(!!!grouping))
  colnames(temp)[2] = paste0(colnames(temp)[1], "_proportion")
  colnames(temp)[3] = paste0(colnames(temp)[1], "_count")
  return(temp)
}

group_and_summarize_demo(mtcars, cyl)
group_and_summarize_demo(mtcars, "cyl", quosure=F)
```

Obviously, in your final code you should choose one of these and stick to it.

#### EDIT:

If you only pass one variable at a time, using the ellipsis looks quite overkill and makes things complicated. Moreover, your example did not seem to work with several variables (`group_and_summarize_demo(mtcars, cyl, vs)`). You might want to consider these few improvements:

```r
library(tidyverse)

group_and_summarize_demo <- function(x, gp_col) {
  gp_col = sym(gp_col)
  temp = x %>% 
    group_by(!!gp_col) %>% 
    summarise("{{gp_col}}_proportion" := mean(am, na.rm = TRUE), 
              "{{gp_col}}_count" := n()) %>% 
    filter(!is.na(!!gp_col))
  temp
}

c("gear", "cyl") %>%  
  map(~group_and_summarize_demo(mtcars, .x)) #try map_dfc() also
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>    gear gear_proportion gear_count
#>   <dbl>           <dbl>      <int>
#> 1     3           0             15
#> 2     4           0.667         12
#> 3     5           1              5
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>     cyl cyl_proportion cyl_count
#>   <dbl>          <dbl>     <int>
#> 1     4          0.727        11
#> 2     6          0.429         7
#> 3     8          0.143        14
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Here, I used the templating [feature](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#one-or-more-user-supplied-expressions) of `dplyr::summarise()` using the `:=` operator. I also used `purrr::map()` instead of the for loop, where the iteration is noted `.x`.